# SwiftUI numberpad(TextField) fail to update the binding variable

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to create a Textfield which allows user to enter information and update the binding variable. Generally, user needs to hit the "return" button after entering the data, so that the compiler will update the data. However, I am now using number pad which have no "return" button. Hence, the compiler fail to update the binding object. What should I do ?

Here is my code:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
     @Published var systemCost = 0
}
```

```
@EnvironmentObject var usersettings: UserSettings

TextField("Please enter here", value: $usersettings.cost, formatter: NumberFormatter())
   .keyboardType(.numberPad)
   .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
   .font(.title)
   .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color("DB"),lineWidth: 1))
```

The cost keep on showing 0 (where the initial value of cost is = 0) after entering a new value.

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you show your `UserSettings` code?

Comment: `class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

   @Published var cost = 0
}`

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? Your model and your TextField are referring to different variables (cost vs systemCost), so there are definitely differences. What I constructed on my own works, so there must be something different in the way you're putting it together.

Comment: I am facing same issue with **TextField** setting formatter to **Number**, if you found solution please share.